# rdd.isEmpty: Cannot resolve symbol isEmpty

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to iterate over `DStream[String] transformed` and for each `RDD[String] rdd` check if it is empty or not using `isEmpty`:

```
transformed.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  if (!rdd.isEmpty) {
    val messages = rdd.map(prepare)
    messages.saveToEs(ec.getResource().toString)
  }
})
```

For some reason `isEmpty` is marked in red (`Cannot resolve symbol isEmpty`). The same happens to symbol `!`. What is wrong with it and how to solve this issue?

Comment: Which Spark version are you running?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: spark 1.0.2

Comment: Spark 1.0.2 [RDD doesn't haven an `isEmpty` method](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD), was added at a later version (1.3.0).

Comment: `isEmpty` was introduced in 1.3.0 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5270).

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Thank you so much!